# GWT Maven Plugin recompiles every time

Tags: gwt, maven

I use GWT Maven Plugin for my GWT project. The problem is that if any class was changed even if it was a server class GWT Maven Plugin recompiles all the GWT code upon running `mvn package`.

How does this plugin determines that recompilation is needed? How could I make it more smart?

Comment: Why do you need to run mvn package frequently?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two solutions :

1st) Add **gwt.compiler.skip=true** to your Maven command line

```
mvn -Dgwt.compiler.skip=true package
```

2nd) Comment the **compile goal** of gwt-maven-plugin plugin in your pom.xml file

```
[...]
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    [...]
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <configuration>
            [...]
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <!--
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                -->
                </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [this](https://gwt-maven-plugin.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html) ? There are some useful options, like gwt.compiler.skip, and some others

Comment: If I add this param, where gwt part will be taken from after a mvn clean ? What is the behaviour in this case ?