# GWT module may need to be (re)compiled

Tags: gwt, maven-3

I can run my app in development mode without any problems. But sometimes it is necessary to test the app without the gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997. Everytime I try this I get the above mentioned exception. Thanks to Thomas answer in this post: [GWT module may need to be (re)compiled REDUX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719118/gwt-module-may-need-to-be-recompiled-redux) I know what causes the problem. I didn't find a way to solve it yet.

I am Using maven and use the target directory to run the app from. When I run the app (gwt:run) after building it (clean install) the *.nochache.js file is overwritten causing the error. 
I have another app where this doesn't happen. But I cannot figure out what is different. Most of the pom stuff seems the same. 
Can anybody help me with this? Do you need more information?

Regards, 
arne

Answer (score 1):

Please check your build path is set to correct output folder.

Also please compile the project and make sure it compiles with 6 permutations.

The compiler version should also be compatible.

Also refer the following link.
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/usingeclipse.html

Comment: build path is correct, why 6 permutations? during development I just need one (firefox+ default language); Compiling works, the problem is just that when I start the development mode my nocache is overwriten.

Comment: Please go through the link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862746/gwt-maven-plugin-recompiles-every-time

Comment: hmm seemed like a really good idea, but i didn't get it to work. The skip parameter just prevents the gwt plugin to compile when I run mvn install. maven-compiler-plugin runs regardless of this option. when I run gwt:run I seems to have no affect. Whats weird, my nocache file is replaced the moment the development mode window opens.